# GitLab Container Not Accepting WAN Connection

Tags: docker, synology, gitlab

Been dealing with this issue for a couple hours now and hit a bit of a standstill as far as my experience and google abilities. Got the most recent version of gitlab installed, after having a similar issue with the built in one of the store. It seems the one in the store is out of date, so i'd rather keep the newer one if possible, but both i cannot seem to connect via the WAN.

Previously, I was getting

`me.git Crostini-Test-Branch ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

But now it just gets stuck

`ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection timed out fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

I was trying to also follow git clone error: Permission denied (publickey,password). fatal: Could not read from remote repository (#4458) · Issues · GitLab.com / GitLab.com Support Tracker but it didn't seem to help so i put it back on 22.

--Edit Scratch that, it's still giving me the error again.

`ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Comment: Are you attempting to connect to SSH inside the Docker container?  If so, have you mapped the container SSH port to an available host port?  Also, you have not shared any configuration information that would help us assist you.  The Dockerfile, the Dcoker image you are using, and the command you start your container with, would all be helpful when supplied with your question.

Comment: I'm using a synology NAS to manage the docker. It is the https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/ and yes I've got the ssh port 30001 mapped to 22 on the container. I'm almost positive that it's working because i have the same setup 30000 mapped to 80 for the web interface and the router's configuration is forwarded for 30000-30001 and the web gui is working.